# How to correctly inter-convert between two related infinitesimals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following input text

```
Clear[ρ, ν, λ, T, h, c, kB]
λ[ν_] := c/ν
ρ[ν_, T_] := (8 πh/c^3) (ν^3/(Exp[h ν/(kB T)] - 1)) \[DifferentialD]ν

ρ[ν, T]
ρ[λ, T]
```

is employed to get the expression for $\rho [\lambda ,T]$, which is expected to be (equivalent to) $$     \frac{8 \pi hc}{\lambda^5}\;\frac{d\lambda }{ \exp \left(\frac{h c}{\lambda 
    k_\text{B} T}\right)-1}     $$

but turns out to be

```
(8 λ^3 πh \[DifferentialD]λ)/(c^3 (-1 + E^((λ)/(kB T))))
```

which visually appears \[     \frac{8 \lambda^3 \pi h\; d\lambda}{c^3 [\exp \left(\frac{h \lambda} 
    {k_\text{B} T}\right)-1]} \]

As can be told by comparison, $\lambda$ is literally substituted for $\nu$. Could you help to suggest how to correctly inter-convert between two related infinitesimals?

Comment: It seems that I cannot use $$ or \\[] to display the equations: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon...

Comment: Use `Dt` instead of `\[DifferentialD]` (and declare `c` to be a constant, e.g., `SetAttributes[c,Constant]` or `Dt[..., Constants->{c}]`).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Could you help to provide an input text that works ?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain how you got your expected answer. It is not clear to me why it is correct.

Comment: @Somos cf. wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law

Comment: @Somos The `ρ[ν, T]` and `ρ[λ, T]` corresponds to equations 1.2 and 1.3 in "Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach" by Donald A. McQuarrie. Sorry for not clarifying. PS: it seems my visual display helper for the input text block is gone, probably by some one's editing. PS: Similar equations can be seen at https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/01%3A_The_Dawn_of_the_Quantum_Theory/1.2%3A_Quantum_Hypothesis_Used_for_Blackbody_Radiation_Law 1.2.5 and 1.2.6

Comment: eq 1.2.5 and 1.2.6 seem to be different from eq 1.2 and 1.3 in the book: (1) hbar in place of h; (2) c^2 instead of c^3 and c, respectively
 https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/01%3A_The_Dawn_of_the_Quantum_Theory/1.2%3A_Quantum_Hypothesis_Used_for_Blackbody_Radiation_Law

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following (revised) code comes close to what you want:

```
SetAttributes[c, Constant];    
Clear[\[Rho], \[Nu], \[Lambda], T, h, c, kB];
\[Lambda][\[Nu]_] := c/\[Nu];
\[Nu] /: Dt[\[Nu]] = DifferentialD[\[Nu]];
\[Lambda] /: Dt[\[Lambda]] = 1/ Dt[\[Lambda][\[Nu]], \[Nu]] DifferentialD[\[Lambda]];
\[Rho][x_, T_: T] := (8 \[Pi] h/c^3) (x^3/(Exp[h x/(kB T)] - 1)) Dt[x];

\[Rho][\[Nu]]
-\[Rho][\[Lambda][\[Nu]]]/. \[Nu]->\[Lambda]
```

using the Wikipedia [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) article as a guide.

I am not sure why the code does the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But the result is not correct. For example, the $\lambda$ should be on the denominator and there should be no $c$.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts to help !

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @AccidentalFourierTransform and @Somos, the following input text meets my need

```
Clear[\[Rho], \[Nu], \[Lambda], T, h, c, kB]
SetAttributes[{h, c, kB}, Constant]

\[Rho][argWhichShouldRepresentFreq_, 
  T_] := (8 \[Pi]h/
     c^3) (argWhichShouldRepresentFreq^3/(Exp[
       h argWhichShouldRepresentFreq/(kB T)] - 1)) Dt[
   argWhichShouldRepresentFreq]

\[Rho][\[Nu], T]
\[Rho][c/# &[\[Lambda]], T]
```

and the following input text uses `/:` to display better

```
Clear[\[Rho], \[Nu], \[Lambda], T, h, c, kB]
SetAttributes[{h, c, kB}, Constant]

\[Rho][argWhichShouldRepresentFreq_, 
  T_] := (8 \[Pi]h/
     c^3) (argWhichShouldRepresentFreq^3/(Exp[
       h argWhichShouldRepresentFreq/(kB T)] - 1)) Dt[
   argWhichShouldRepresentFreq]

\[Nu] /: Dt[\[Nu]] = DifferentialD[\[Nu]]
\[Lambda] /: Dt[\[Lambda]] = DifferentialD[\[Lambda]]

\[Rho][\[Nu], T]
\[Rho][c/# &[\[Lambda]], T]
```